# find specific cells according to an order with constraints

Tags: excel

i need help on excel 
i have table looking like this(it's an example):

```
        cheese   tomato  chocolate  cream 
Pizza      2       3                     
cake                        1          1
```

And i want to have names of ingredients for each plates from the highest one to the lowest if we consider that the numbers are the lead time for each ingredient and if the lead time is the same i don't want to have the same name in both cells. 
like this:

```
           Ingredient 1   Ingredient 2   ingredient3
pizza        tomato          cheese        nothing
cake         chocolate       cream
```

thank you, please help :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make yourself comfortable with [**the asking guide**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add more information to your question that helps readers to be able to reproduce your problem. Also please try choosing the proper tags. Currently it's impossible to tell what exactly you are asking for, as there is basically no context.

Comment: well we can't help you the question is unreadable try rewriting your question please

Answer (score 0):

Try the formula as shown in the image,

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$E$1,MATCH(LARGE($B2:$E2,COLUMN(A1)),$B2:$E2,0)),"nothing")`

[image]

Am not sure how you want to represent data if the lead time is same. The formula currently shows chocolate twice. You may have to alter it according to your needs. Drag the formula to right and then down for the complete range.